# I want storybook addon actions to display its standard "log" message AND the actual component event handler to update the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I can't seem to figure out how to get my event handling function to do its logic to update the UI AND storybook's addon - `actions()` to log the output.

The reason I want the UI to update is because we're using cypress.io for testing. We've hacked/stubbed the actions messaging (pretty cool, window.postMessage) to access the action message which allows the use of `action("functionName")`, instead of wiring up a event handling function in `[file].stories.tsx`. I'd like to do both for my sanity. To check the action message, its a few clicks. I'd rather just see the item get removed. With that, for testing, I'd like to expect the action message (I'm able to do that). We are using `alert()` to check if something fired, and I'm not a fan.

If this just seems unnecessary, or counter intuitive/productive, do elaborate.

If it helps... `<List />` is just that, but has an *action* button on each *item* to remove the item from the list.

Using `onRemove={actionHandler}` prop, below, in List does just that in the UI, removes the item and Cypress is happy, but need the `alert()` to track. But cant wire up the `action()` anywhere and no log in the GUI.

If I REMOVE `onRemove={actionHandler}` and uncomment `// onRemove: action("removeItem")`, I get the action log I want, but the Item doesn't remove.

I understand actions are supposed to mimic event handler's, but I'd like it to do that AND fire the actual event... if possible or reasonable.

```js
List.stories.tsx
// storybook addons
import { withKnobs } from "@storybook/addon-knobs";

// deps
import React from "react";
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions";

// utils
import { CustomEvent } from "../../hooks";

// components
import { Item } from "./Item"
import { List } from "./ListItems"
import { InputHeader } from "../inputs/InputHeader";

// create test states for target dropdown
export default {
  component: List,
  title: "Lists|With Action",
  decorators: [withKnobs]
};

const listItemsData = {
    values: ['Test Value 1', 'Test Value 2', 'Test Value 3', 'Test Value 4', 'Test Value 5'],
    name: "test list story",
    // onRemove: action("removeItem")
};

export const listWithActionButton = () => {
    const [listItemState, setListItemState] = React.useState(listItemsData)
    const actionHandler = (event: CustomEvent<string[]>) => {
        // action("removeItem")()
        setListItemState(prevState => ({
            ...listItemState,
            values: event.target.value,
        }))
    };

    return (
        <>
        <InputHeader headerText="List with Action Buttons" />
        <br/>
        <List 
            {...listItemState}
            onRemove={actionHandler}
            />
        </>
    )
};

List.tsx
export const List = ({name, values, onRemove}) => {
  const removeItem = (index: number) => {
      // this is what I want to fire AS WELL as the action log.
      const top = values.slice(0, index);
      const bottom = values.slice(index + 1);
      const updatedOptions = [...top, ...bottom]

      // Fire a custom event to match what our useForm hook expects
      const event: CustomEvent<string[]> = {
        target: {
          value: updatedOptions,
          name
        },
      };
      return onRemove(event);
    };

    return (
        <ListStyle>
            {
                values.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Item 
                            key={index} 
                            value={item} 
                            removeItem={removeItem}
                            itemIndex={index}
                        />)
                })
            }
        </ListStyle>
    )
};
```

Comment: `onRemove={(...args) => { action('log'); actionHandler(...args); }}` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this if you want to fire an action AND execute your function.

```
  <Button
    onClick={(e) => {
      action('click')(e);
      removeItem();
    }}
    selected={state}
  >
```